# get last 2 tokens from a variable in Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i need to get **the last 2 tokens from a variable** in Batch

the variable is

```
Rastreando a rota para user722-PC [192.168.1.106]
```

the output i need is a variable containing

```
user722-PC
```

and another containing

```
[192.168.1.106]
```

and no, i cant use

```
for /f "tokens=5,6 delims= " %%a in ("%variable%") do set host=%%a & set ip=%%b
echo %ip% %host%
```

because in this case i specified tokens 5,6 and what i want to to is to get the last 2 tokens dynamicaly, so i must NOT specify any token numbers mannualy

// this way i can get only the last token, considering that the delimiter is a space, and the delimiter cant be changed

```
FOR %%a in (%variable%) do set lastPart=%%a
ECHO %lastPart%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "variable=Rastreando a rota para user722-PC [192.168.1.106]"
FOR %%a IN (%variable%) DO CALL SET "lastbut1=%%lastpart%%"&SET "lastpart=%%a"
SET last

GOTO :EOF
```

`call`ing the `set` re-parses it, so `set "lastbut1=%lastpart%"` is executed in a subshell.

This could also be done using `delayedexpansion` about which there are many articles on SO.

---

The short explanation for how it works is ***** MAGIC *****

A longer explanation is this:

the commands `CALL SET "lastbut1=%%lastpart%%"` and `SET "lastpart=%%a"` are executed in that sequence for each element in `%variable%` which is a simple string with elements separated by spaces, tabs, commas or semicolons.

The <kbd>&</kbd> is used to separate the commands and serves merely to allow many commands to be specified on he same physical line. The code could also be written

```
(
 CALL SET "lastbut1=%%lastpart%%"
 SET "lastpart=%%a"
)
```

which is exactly the same; the parentheses are required and enclose the individual commands. There an additional syntax-requirement here. The opening `(` must be on the same physical line as the `do`.

The `CALL SET "lastbut1=%%lastpart%%"` executes `SET "lastbut1=%lastpart%"` in a sub-shell, setting `lastbut1` to the *current* value of `lastpart`. Then the `SET "lastpart=%%a"` sets `lastpart` to the value in `%%a`.

So, on the next iteration, `lastbut1` gets the value that was applied to `lastpart` in the prior iteration, and so on until the very last time, when `lastpat` acquires the very last item on the list and `lastbut1` has just been assigned the value just before that.

Hence, to get `lastbut2`, all you'd need would be to use

```
FOR %%a IN (%variable%) DO call set "lastbut2=%%lastbut1%%&CALL SET "lastbut1=%%lastpart%%"&SET "lastpart=%%a"
```

which sets `lastbut2` from `lastbut1`, `lastbut1` from `lastpart` and `lastpart` from `%%a` in that sequence.

Comment: if i wanted to get the lastbut2 instead of lastbut1, how would i do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "var=Rastreando a rota para user722-PC [192.168.1.106]"
set "last=%var: =" & set "lastBut1=!last!" & set "last=%"
SET last
```

Hint: run this program with `@echo on`

Comment: @Magoo you should come hang out on dostips.com. They figure out all kinds of whack stuff like that all the time.